# What is a good tool to get SQL code completion with SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried Red Gate's SQL Prompt and like it, but cannot afford it at the moment.  I miss the good code completion that this tool provides.  Are there any good free tools out there that have SQL code completion (table and column names, etc)?

I've tried TOAD, but it was quite buggy.  It would crash, and would also leave connections open to the database after the app was closed.

I'm also aware that SQL Server 2008 has some form of code completion, but it requires that the database you are connected to be 2008, not just the Management Studio version.  My employer will eventually upgrade, but I believe this may be a while in coming, so I'd like a good tool in the interim.

Any good recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Red Gate's [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm) is what you want. It's not free, but it **is** worth it.

Comment: I appreciate the endorsement, and I agree.  However, I specifically asked for tools *other* than SQL Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a few different tools myself, and nothing really compared to SQL Prompt.

I personally recommend contacting Red Gate if you like the tool, they are known to have "specials" at given times where you might be able to get a discount, especially this time of the month.

Otherwise, contact me and I get get you 5% off anyway

Answer (score 0):

When RedGate bought SQL Prompt, they put out the current version at the time for free.  That's what I'm still using.  It's not as solid as the new one, but it doesn't have issues with remote servers - which is what i use for most of the day.  See if you can get your hands on a copy of that.  (version 2.0.0.59)